# Why is my C# TCP client receiving garbage sometimes?

Tags: c#, networking, godot, garbage

If the server sends 2 items of data at almost the same time, the client receives the 2nd item of data. It will have about 75% to receive garbage.

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the C# client:

1. I've printed the buffer in the server - everything is correct
2. Used Wireshark to check the buffer - everything is correct
3. And used Python to receive the data instead of using C# - seems to be correct

I tried:

1. Clear the buffer when receiving - nothing happened
2. Adding a delay before the receive functions - it worked. But I'm not sure how long I should wait. And because of the probability of getting the correct data, it might not be the correct way to fix this. Also, as a game I want to receive data as quickly as it can.

This is the code about network in the client:

(*This client uses GODOT - I've deleted parts of the code that isn't about receiving data*)

```cs
public partial class Network : Node
{
    public bool error = false; // Happened Error.

    private Socket socket = null; // The Socket File.
    private Change change = new Change(); // The Changer To Change Packages And Bytes.
    private byte[] buffer = new byte[64]; // The Buffer.
    private List<Tuple<object, PackageType>> packageGet = new List<Tuple<object, PackageType>>(); // The Packages Got And Not Handled.

    public override void _ExitTree()
    {
        close();
    }

        public override void _Process(double delta) // 
        {
            if (!updated && packageGet.Count > 0)
            {
                handleEvent();
            }
        }

    /**
     * @brief Connect To The Server.
     * @param ipParameter The IP Address.
     * @return The Result.
     */
    public bool connect(string ipParameter)
    {
        close();
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        try
        {
            if (!socket.ConnectAsync(ipParameter, 10000).Wait(ConfigPanel.connectTime))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        startRead();
        
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @brief Close The Socket.
     */
    public void close()
    {
        if (socket != null && socket.Connected)
        {
            socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            socket.Close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @breif Start To Read Data From Server.
     */
    private void startRead()
    {
        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, read, null);
    }

    /**
     * @breif Read Data Got (Callback From startRead()).
     * @param resultParameter The Result.
     */
    private void read(IAsyncResult resultParameter)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!socket.Connected || socket == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            int length = socket.EndReceive(resultParameter);

            if (length == 0)
            {
                close();
// Error
                return;
            }

            PackageType type = PackageType.None;
            object package = change.toPackage(buffer, ref type);
            packageGet.Add(new Tuple<object, PackageType>(package, type));
            startRead();
        }
        catch
        {
// Error
        }
    }

    /**
     * @brief Handle The Events.
     */
    private void handleEvent()
    {
                // Just Handle
    }
}
```

Sorry for the bad indentation :(, Thanks for helping.

Comment: Define garbage... Also you don't take received lenght into account

Comment: Randomly data is garbage. And what's the account?

Comment: Well in buffer there will be the garbage (leftover from previous data) after index defined by received length

Comment: It'll still have garbage even I cleared the buffer before recv?

Comment: Again, check if lenght of recevide is the length you want in other case you need to wait for whole data before parsing package(multiple received and build buffer) ...

Comment: The naive way is to build simple protocol which sends lenght before data and after receiving lenght, read until you fill up buffer to this lenght and then parse... You are wrongly assuming that single send on other side will cause single receive on your side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is a streaming protocol, not a message protocol; when calling `Read`/`Receive`/etc:

- the number of bytes **must** be respected - everything beyond that is (as you say): garbage
- your message can be fragmented over any number of receive calls: all that is guaranteed is that each receive will get *at least* one byte, or an EOF

as such, you need to a: respect `length`, and b: implement some kind of framing protocol; usually this means something like "the first 4 bytes of any message are the length, in little-endian int32, of the message that follows", so: you'd buffer at least 4 bytes (possibly over 4 receive calls, although in reality: usually 1), parse the length, then buffer at least that many bytes (possibly over many receive calls), and *then* parse the message. If you have over-read (i.e. in the "at least", you consumed more): then you need to retain that backlog too.

Honestly, it is easier to use the "pipelines" model, which simplifies all this buffer management; there's a 3-and-a-bit series of mine [here](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html) on that topic, although it is quite a paradigm shift.

Answer (score 0):

Please take my answer with caution as i am a beginner myself, and my answer might be wrong.
My answer is maybe not what you expect, and maybe cou cant even use it with your approach, but i still feel like leaving it here, as it might help you maybe?

I recently did a chat application using tcp, but i receive messages a bit different:
Instead of your `socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, read, null);`

I used `var amountBytes = await _clientSocket.ReceiveAsync(bytes);`
Like already said, tcp doesnt guarantee to send something in chucks you like to. So maybe its wise to put a identifyer at the end of each complete Datamodel, so you can use it like this:

```
string decodedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, amountBytes);
                    buffer += decodedMessage;

                    //If we already received a complete message model
                    if (buffer.Contains(_endOfMessageIdentifyer))
                    {
                        //get the index of the start of the identifyer 
                        int index = decodedMessage.IndexOf(_endOfMessageIdentifyer);
                        //Cut everything before the identifyer out
                        string completeDatamodel = decodedMessage.Substring(0, index);
                        //Cut everything after the identifyer out
                        string remainingData = decodedMessage.Substring(index + _endOfMessageIdentifyer.Length);

                        buffer = remainingData;
```

With this approach, you are safe to always have exact one datamodel which you can process.